# How to make jemdoc executable in Windows 10 command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I'm just trying to run `jemdoc` in Windows 10 command prompt, as explained [here](https://github.com/wsshin/jemdoc_mathjax), by

```
jemdoc -c mysite.conf index.jemdoc
```

where, both `mysite.conf` and `index.jemdoc` are in the same directory as `jemdoc`. However, I receive this error:

```
'jemdoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have already added `jemdoc` directory to the path.

So, how can I make that `jemdoc` executable?

Comment: If you navigate to the directory that contains the executable does the command work? This is obviously a case where the directory isn’t contained within the PATH system variable

Comment: @Ramhound: No, it does not. I get the same error when I run the command in the directory.

Comment: That should be impossible.  Did you include the file extension if the file?

Comment: @Ramhound: Which file extension do you mean?

Comment: The file extension of the file.  Do you have a compatible version of Python install on your system?

Comment: The file extension is `.py` which yields the same error, should one uses it. My python version is 3.8 which should be compatible with the file, per its developer's assertion.

Comment: The project hasn’t been touched in years (I looked at the documentation). You have tried calling Python before the file name?

Comment: @Ramhound: Running `python jemdoc.py` prints the documentation in command prompt, again, claiming that `jemdoc index.jemdoc` should work, which doesn't!

Comment: And if you issue the same full command you were using to include Python does it work?